# Positioning form inputs using twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to position some input fields in a form, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get it right. I want to have the form centered in the page with each input labeled and have the inputs have two or three to a line up to a point. No matter what I try everything is either off center or it doesn't seem to do anything. Any help is appreciated. My code is below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveNew", "MaintainProjects", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary();
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
@Html.Hidden("PriorityCode", "0000")
<div class ="control-group">
        <div class ="controls form-inline">
@Html.Label("Name")
@Html.TextBox("Name")
@Html.Label("Status")
@Html.TextBox("Status")

            </div>
</div>
    <div class ="control-group">
        <div class ="controls form-inline">
 @Html.Label("WatchList")
 @Html.CheckBox("WatchList")
            </div>
        </div>
<div class ="control-group">
        <div class ="controls form-inline">
@Html.Label("Goal")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GoalID, new SelectList(Model.GoalID, "GoalID", "Goal"))
@Html.Label("Level")
<select name="LevelID">
    <option value="1">Non-TSC</option>
    <option value="2">TSC</option>
</select> 
            </div>
    </div>
<div class ="control-group">
        <div class ="controls form-inline">
@Html.Label("Indicator")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IndicatorID, new SelectList(Model.IndicatorID, "IndicatorID", "ProjectIndicator"))
@Html.Label("Business")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LOBID, new SelectList(Model.LOBID, "LOBId", "LOB", Model.LOBID[0].LOBId))
@Html.Label("Department")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DepartmentID, new SelectList(Model.DepartmentID, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName"))
            </div>
    </div>
<p>Project Description</p>
<div class ="control-group">
        <div class ="controls form-inline">
@Html.Label("Business Issue")
@Html.TextArea("BusinessIssue", new { @rows = "3" })
            </div>
    </div>
<div class ="control-group">
        <div class ="controls form-inline">
@Html.Label("Solution")
@Html.TextArea("Solution", new { @rows = "3" })
            </div>
    </div>
<div class ="control-group">
        <div class ="controls form-inline">
@Html.Label("Benefits")
@Html.TextArea("Benefits", new { @rows = "3" })
            </div>
    </div>
<div class ="control-group">
        <div class ="controls form-inline">
@Html.Label("Project Directory")
@Html.TextBox("ProjectDirectory")   
            </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to achieve. A screenshot of the mock up would be great. It appears you should not be placing "form-inline" class all over. For example, usually this class is not placed on contol-group elements. Though the code is such a mess I didn't look too hard. Check out [TwitterBootstrapMvc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc). It will make your code cleaner. You will be able to write something like this with it:

```
@using (Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form().Type(FormType.Horizontal)))
{
    @Html.Bootstrap().ValidationSummary()

    @Html.Bootstrap().ControlGroup().CheckBox("WatchList")
    @Html.Bootstrap().ControlGroup().DropDownListFor(m => m.LOBID, new SelectList(Model.LOBID, "LOBId", "LOB", Model.LOBID[0].LOBId))
    @Html.Bootstrap().ControlGroup().TextArea("BusinessIssue")
}
```

I didn't write all your inputs, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Due to some constraints I can't use TwitterBootstrapMvc. I really just need to organize the inputs into rows if that generalizes it more.

Comment: Then you can start by tyding you code that you posted so that it's actually readable (formatting is horrible) and posting a screenshot of desired outcome